# How to swipe Up, Down, Left and right in appium Java IOS

Tags: java, ios, maven, appium

.moveTo() // 
shows this error: The method moveTo(PointOption) is undefined for the type WaitOptions.

I do the provided quick fix which is: add cast to method receiver

Following error shows:
The method waitAction(WaitOptions) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (TouchAction)

java version "1.8.0_191"
Simulator - iPhone x (IOS 12)
Appium 1.9.0

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    org.openqa.selenium.Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction) {
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
            action.press(PointOption.point(427, 878))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions
                    .waitOptions(Duration
                            .ofMillis(1300))
                    .moveTo(PointOption.point(427, 554))
                    .release().perform();

            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

        case UP:
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

    }
}
```

If use

public enum DIRECTION {   LEFT  }

I expect it to swipe left

Answer (score 1):

`waitAction` method does not accept `java.time.Duration duration` it has to be passed using `waitOptions` as you have used in `RIGHT` case. Check `waitOptions` details [here](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/touch/WaitOptions.html)

Similarly `moveTo` and `press` accept `PointOptions` and directly coordinates cannot be passed.

```
    case LEFT:
        startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
       startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
        endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
        new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(PointOption.point(startX, startY))
                .waitAction(WaitOptions
                .waitOptions(Duration
                        .ofMillis(duration))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, startY))
                .release()
                .perform();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but 
moveTO shows an error: The method moveTo(PointOption) is undefined for the type WaitOptions. 
if i apply the quick fix which is 'add cast to method receiver', then the following error occurs:

The method waitAction(WaitOptions) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (TouchAction)